# Take last variable from text file and its time

Tags: python

I am using Circuitpython for my microcontroller. I am writing whatever my microcontroller do when internet is gone to text file like this:

```
[{'name': 'exampleA', 'time': '2022-03-15 15:12:55.12541', 'id': '5456431', 'howmany': 2, 'character':None}]
```

exampleA can repeat in this text file, I always need to check last exampleA's values. So I wrote this;

```
string = exampleA  # it will be taken from user.
file = open("example.txt")
for line in reversed(file.readlines()):
    if string in line:
        print(len(file.read()))
        print(string)
```

When I found `exampleA`, how can I take `exampleA`'s time too? Because for example if microcontroller do something with `exampleA`, it shouldn't do things for at least 3 hour. So I need to take last `exampleA`'s time.

Comment: Is each line a valid Python `repr`? (Is there a reason you wrap the dictionary in a list? Perhaps use JSON in your file instead of Python literals.)

Comment: Once you have read all the data into memory, you can no longer `file.read()` unless you close and reopen the file, or rewind it with `seek`. But the data is already in memory; examine the variable you are looping over instead of trying to read the file some more. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: I need to read this file when internet is gone. If I have internet, I can take datas from api but when internet is gone, microcontroller have to do this by itself and when internet is connected, it needs to post this text.file to api.

Comment: tripleee, thank you for explanation.